# Is the ellipse in the mentioned sentence idiomatic?

Tags: ellipsis, idiomatic-language

> They rarely teach for its own sake but most of the time **[they]** use 
>   teaching as a way to manipulate.

Is it idiomatic to omit the second "they" in the above sentence?

Comment: The sentence is not idiomatic. It is not clear what *its* refers to. *Its*, like *his*, *her*, *their*, is a ‘possessive  pronoun’, so we expect it to refer to a noun. What noun does *its* refer to? *Teach* is not a noun in your sentence, so idiomatically it cannot refer to that. One’s best guess is that *its* refers  to a noun that is in a sentence that comes before the one you ask about.

Answer (score 4):

This ellipsis may be pushing the boundaries of good communication, but it is perfectly proper grammatically to use a single subject for multiple verbs.

"Mary wrote and sang the songs heard that night" is idiomatic and grammatical.

However, in your example, there is a fairly extensive bit of other material separating the verbs, and a skilled writer would likely respond to that separation either by repeating the subject or by bringing the two verbs closer together or by using parallelism. I might re-write as follows:

"They rarely teach to educate but instead teach to indoctrinate."

I want to stress that I am not taking a position on grammar. I am making a point on style.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty good with or without the second pronoun; I'd leave it out but it's not “wrong”.

Personally I'd add **rather** after the **but**.